# Can't create connection between HTML form web part and list (works on one but not the other)

Tags: custom-list, data-view-web-part, html-form-web-part

I'm trying to use an HTML form web part as a search feature on a data view on a page and then also send that same form value to connect to another list on that page.  It is using the same field and using the same value.

It works fine when I use it for the first data view.  When I add the connection to the second one and submit a value I get the error page `An unexpected error has occurred. Web parts maintenance page:...`.  I took off both connections and tried only applying it to the second list, this also throws the same error.  I thought maybe the difference between a data view web part and a list web part might have something to do with it so I created a data view for the second list.  This didn't fix the error either.

There must be something different between my two web parts but I have no idea what it is.  I haven't used HTML form web parts often either so I don't know if they can be buggy or not.  Has anyone encountered anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced something similar when attempting to create a connection to send a filter value from one web part to another, in a *customized* display form. The error is given when attempting the connection - "No provider schema." This occurs only when attempting such a connection on a form other than the original form - i.e. it only happens with new forms I've created in Designer. The connection is always successful when done on the original form.

It is obvious --and has been reported by others in various posts elsewhere-- that new forms don't contain all the code, or different code, that original forms. (I know too little to determine which part of the code from the original form contains the essential and missing values, or to even tell if the missing pieces are in the form code at all.) The obvious workaround is to just use the original form...except that only in non-original forms can the form body HTML be edited, to remove or reorder fields for instance.

It's not clear exactly the scenario you're describing (or if it involves forms in the same way I'm referring to them, at all). But if it involves any non-original display, edit, or new forms try repeating the connection with the original copy of the form.